# Find the least positive integer value of $a$ for which such a polynomial exists.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider a polynomial of the form $ax^2 - bx + c$ with integer coefficients, such that it has two distinct zeros in the open interval $0 < x < 1.$ Find the least positive integer value of $a$ for which such a polynomial exists.

---

Open interval?  What's that?  And how would I approach this problem?  Solution are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open [interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)) $0 < x < 1$ is the set of all real numbers $x$ that are (strictly) greater than $0$ and (strictly) less than $1$.  So the question is saying there are two distinct zeros, and both are strictly between $0$ and $1$.

Let $f(x)$ be your polynomial.  The minimum of $f(x)$ is at $x = b/(2a)$, which must be between $0$ and $1$.  The value of $f(x)$ there is $c - b^2/(4a)$, which must be $< 0$.  The values of $f(x)$ at $x=0$ and $x=1$ are
$c$ and $a-b+c$, which must be $>0$.

It seems to me that the least possible positive integer $a$ is $5$, for which
$b=5$, $c=1$ works, for example.

Comment: Essentially this is an integer nonlinear programming problem where the goal is to find _any_ interior point. Yes, $5x^2-5x+1$ satisfies all the conditions and has the smallest possible value of $a$.